# Enabling Ctrl+Alt+Del for X

Tags: graphics, xorg, usability

How to I re-enbale the feature where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> will immediately kill X? I've been running into a graphics bug and I realized that, that was disabled in Ubuntu 16.10 for some reason. How do I get that functionality back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a terminal and run:

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/keyboard`

*instead of `gedit` you can use any other text editor that you have installed as `leafpad`

In the opened document, search for `XKBOPTIONS=""` and edit it so it looks like this `XKBOPTIONS="terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"`

Save the file and reboot.

Comment: *gksu* is no longer installed by default. For the same purpose the preferred method now is *sudo -H*.